# Installing a new Motherboard in a HP xw6200 case

Tags: motherboard, case

I have a HP xw6200 Workstation, that is rather long in the tooth, and with 2 physical CPUs, it is quite inefficient. So, the plan was to upgrade the internals.

Nothing special:

- AMD Athlon II X4 640
- ASUS M4A78KT-M LE (mATX)
- 2x 2GB DDR3 1333MHz RAM.
  3p under my £150 budget

The issues:
The pin connector for the front panel isn't a good fit, but I can trim it to size.

The PSU has a 8-Pin Power connector, unsurprisingly, the new board has a 4 pin socket. The pins do line up, but I would have to cut it in half to fit.

Finally, due to the weight of heat-sinks, they are screwed directly into the case. It turns out that these screws also lock the motherboard in place. As to remove it, you remove the heat-sinks, slide the motherboard across and lift it out.

I tested the new board for fit, and while it slots in fine, it's not secure. There is nowhere to screw the board down, it is just held in place with plastic standoffs. The only idea I had, was to wedging something between the side of the motherboard and part of the case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier to buy a new case than to mess about with the old one.

On the back of that; I am actually looking for a HP xw6200 case.
As long as you've not completely chopped it up or messed too much with it, I'd possibly be interested in buying the case from you.

If you are located in the UK?

Jason.

Comment: I used a different case in the end. So didn't touch the xw6200 case. I am located in the UK, near Mansfield. If you are still interested send me an e-mail at thing2k at gmail.

Comment: You should have an email winging it's way to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would install a proper power supply, not worth the risk of frying a new mobo.

You should mark some of the new motherboard screw holes on the case so you can install some standoffs, it may take some drilling and tapping of new threads to install the mobo standoffs, but will be worth the time.

Front panel pin locations may not match the new motherboard, I would trace the wires to the front panel to be sure they are going to the proper pins on the new motherboard or you could damage the new mobo.

Comment: I have traced the wire for the front panel, and they are correct. IIRC all of the mobo screw holes line up with spaces for the plastic slide in standoffs for the original board. Will have another look tonight. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, sometimes the connectors are standard but sometimes not, better to check before you power it up. Sometimes you can replace the plastic stands with the screw type. Sounds like a fun project.